# Get-ADUser -Filter fails when comparing to an object's property

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a powershell question that has to do with importing a csv file, then going through a foreach through the csv file.

I have something like the following:

```
$infile = "c:\temp\infile.csv"
$outfile = "c:\temp\outfile.csv"

$csv = Import-csv -path $infile
foreach ($line in $csv)
{
  $data = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $line.email} -Property Mail |     Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
}
```

When I do something like that, I get the following error:

```
Get-ADUser : Property: 'email' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
At C:\Temp\program1.ps1:11 char:24
+         $ad_data = Get-ADUser <<<<  -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $line.email} -Property Mail | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Property: 'email' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

But if I do something like:

```
    $var = $line.email
    $data = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $var} -Property Mail | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
```

Why does the second method works but the first method throws an error?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to rename `$line` to avoid potential conflicts (depends on how Get-ADUser is implemented). Does this help?

Comment: Or this kind of filter is not supported. See the details [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx). Perhaps not all values are supported: *"For a list of supported types for <value>, see about_ActiveDirectory_ObjectModel."*

Comment: I've got to say that I do not know why you're having this issue, I've done some research and have found a forum thread with a lot of folks discussing this problem, and no one had a good solution.  I'll see what I can find out from the other MVPs.

Answer (score 7):

Alright, I had a discussion with some of my fellow PowerShell MVPs, and the answer as to why is really quite interesting.

For the quick answer, this is how you do get the AD User while preserving the structure of your code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Emailaddress -eq '$($line.email)'"
```

You can quickly test to see what is happening by just running the quoted code on its own:

```
"Emailaddress -eq '$($line.email)'"
>Emailaddress -eq 'Jim.Adkison@foxdeploy.com'
```

As to why, well, the outside set of quotes always wins in PowerShell, and the `*-ADUser -Filter` Cmdlets expect the value to be provided in single quotes.

According to Dave Wyatt, PowerShell MVP and all around cool guy and Mike Robbins, also MVP and well-respected around the community, the way that the ADUser Cmdlets expand variables is somewhat unstandard when compared to the rest of PowerShell's code base.  They described the action of Variable expansion as 'strange voodoo', which seems about right.

If you'd like to learn a little bit more, follow up on Mike's awesomely detailed blog post on just this type of scenario [PowerShell: When Best Practices and Accurate Results Collide](http://mikefrobbins.com/2014/11/06/powershell-when-best-practices-and-accurate-results-collide/)

Comment: -Filter is actually a string type, examples in the docs notwithstanding.  A scriptblock will just get cast to a string.  Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Weird.  It works with `$me = get-aduser somename; get-aduser -filter { samaccountname -eq $me.name }`, but not `$me = [pscustomobject]@{name='somename'}`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a subexpression in the filter?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $($line.email)}
```

From the error, it isn't properly calling your object inside the filter.

For more testing, what is the object type of $line?

```
$line | Get-Member
```